# The latest Admob Ad can't be displayed if I set android:padding in layout, why?

Tags: android, admob

If I use the layout of Case A, the Admob Ad can't be displayed.

If I use the layout of Case B, the Admob Ad can be displayed correctly! I can't understand why?

And more, if I set android:background such as android:background="@drawable/border_ui", the Admob Ad can't be displayed too even if the border_ui.xml is empty.

You can test the sample at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/209352/aa.zip

**Case A**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.aa.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView  
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"       
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="YouID" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Case B**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"   
    tools:context="com.example.aa.MainActivity" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView  
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"       
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="YouID" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**dimens.xml**

```
 <resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**MainActivity Class**

```
package com.example.aa;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private AdView adView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                         .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                         .build();
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

      @Override
      public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (adView != null) {
          adView.resume();
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onPause() {
        if (adView != null) {
          adView.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
      }

      @Override
      public void onDestroy() {
        if (adView != null) {
          adView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
      }


}
```

Comment: as per my knowldge never use padding or any space between adview component or its parent component i also faced same problem so i removed space/padding and it worked for me

Comment: this is because of banner size cause if you gave space or padding then banner is unable to fit in adview may be thats why such kind of issue is coming am not sure but as per my understanding this is the thig i also googled when i encounter such problem

Comment: I think AdView control not enough width or high in Case A. Some of the layout margin need to reduce or remove. Just for thinking. Hope for help. :)

Comment: Thanks! To BM: but I have set ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply the padding in case A means there is not enough room to display the ad. If you look at your log you will see messages to that effect.

SmartBanner just means that an adsize suitable for the device size and resolution is chosen, it doesn't mean that it chooses one that fits any arbitrary screen layout.

Answer (score 0):

latest admob sdk is integrated in googleplayservices which start showing ad after 
adding this to your manifest file

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="5089000"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! I have added  meta-data into my mainifest file and Case B layout can display AD, but Case A can't display AD